# image replacement on click go to next image in folder

Tags: jquery, image, swap, replace

first of all I'm a designer with little to no knowledge in jquery. I'm usually able to do research and find scripts that do what I want and then change them a bit. But this time I already did research for 4 days and still can't find anything that is close enough to what I'm looking for.

Currently I use this script:

```
   $(function(){
      $(".img-swap").live('click', function() {

        if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
          this.src = this.src.replace("_1","_2");
        } else {
          this.src = this.src.replace("_2","_3");
        }
        $(this).toggleClass("on");
      });
    });
```

I have single images on the website. On click the image should be replaced like this:

I have folders with a max of 10 images. They are named 'projectxyz_01.jpg' etc. What I need now is a script that on click replaces 'project_xyz_01.jpg' with 'project_xyz_02.jpg' and so on. If there is no more picture in the folder go back to the first one. It would be nice if the images fade.

The script I currently use does only work to go from 1-3 of course, doesn't fade and doesn't go back to the first image.

This is the image container:

```
        <div class="slideshow_querformat">
            <img src="images/mmd/mmd_test_01.jpg" class="img-swap" border="0" alt="social media webcalender" title="Klicken, um die nächste Arbeit zu sehen." />
        </div>
```

This is the css part:

```
   .slideshow_querformat { 
width:60.25%;
min-width:700px;
height:auto;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
z-index:999;
    }

   .slideshow_querformat img { 
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
cursor:pointer;
margin-left:16px;
    }
```

Comment: The condition that checks whether the class is `img-swap` is redundant. Also, you should use `on` instead of `live`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need something like this

```
$(function(){
  $(".slideshow_querformat").on('click', '.img-swap', function() {
    var self = this,
        file = this.src,
        common = file.substring(0, file.length-6)
        currentId =  +file.substr(-6,2),
        id = ('0' + (currentId+1)).substr(-2),
        nextimage= new Image();

    nextimage.onload = function(){
       // image was preloaded so it exists
       var img = this;
       $(self).fadeOut(300, function(){self.src = img.src; $(self).fadeIn(300)});
    };
    nextimage.onerror = function(){
       // error occured while preloading. we assume image does not exist
       $(self).fadeOut(300, function(){self.src = common+ '01.jpg'; $(self).fadeIn(300)});
    };
    nextimage.src = common + id + '.jpg';
  });
});
```

Demo (*which does not showcase the error case*) at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/3PFGF/

What this script does, is it tries to preload the new image, and if it succeeds it then fades out the current one swaps the `src` attribute and fades-in the new image..

If an error happens (*which we understand as that the image does not exist*) we then set the name to 01 and load fade in to that..

---

Instead of `.live()` which is deprecated, you should use `.on()` but you will have to provide a bit more html (*a container of the image*) if you want a suggestion of how to use it efficiently..

Comment: I added more background info.

Comment: @TimBrack, does the `.slideshow_querformat` element exist all the time? or is it a popup or something that appears after some action ?

Comment: it is visible all the time. Your script already works pretty well. Thank you. Only thing missing is to check, if there are any more pictures. Currently it keeps linking pictures even though there aren't that many in the folder.

Comment: My mistake: It's already there and it's working. Thank you very much, you made my day!

Comment: Last question: When the script loads the first image again, after cycled through all of them there is a split second of where theres no image at all and the page jumps because it's %-based. Any workaround for that?

Comment: @tim, do you have this page somewhere online so I can see it in action ?

Comment: here is a beta version of the site: http://zeiteffekt.de/relaunch/

I guess I know what happens: The jump I encounter when clicking on the last picture of a folder is based on the script going for the error function and loading the first image again.

Comment: It only randomly happens to me, and only from chrome... try replacing the code inside the `onerror` function with just `nextimage.src = common + '01.jpg';`

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the image to fade try using 'fadeOut' with setTimeout function... something like this...

```
setTimeout(function(){$("your_image_id").fadeOut("fast");},2000);
```

here the 2000 is optional, you can make it as you concern... and if you want it to be slow use 'slow' instead of fast...

to get the first image... make a check... like this...

```
if($(this).attr('src') == 'project_xyz_10.jpg') {
  this.src = this.src.replace("_10","_1");
}
```

Might work...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the modulo operator to cycle through images.

```
$(function() {
    $(".img-swap").on('click', function() {
        var src = this.src.substr(-6, 2);
        console.log(src);
        this.src = "project_xyz_" + ("0" + ((parseInt(src) + 1) % 10)).substr(-2) + ".jpg";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to swap images. Here, total will be total number of images you have in the folder.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


   $(function(){
      count = 1;
      total = 4;


      $(".img-swap").on('click', function() {

        $(this).fadeOut(400, function() {
            $(this).attr('src', 'projectxyz_0' + count + '.jpg');
        }).fadeIn(400);

        count ++;

        if(count > total) {
            count = 1;
        }

      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the images as below

```
<img class='img-swap' src='projectxyz_1.jpg'/>

var imgCnt = 10;

$(function() {
    $(".img-swap").live('click', function() {
        var str = $(this).attr('src');
        var strCurrNo = str.substring(str.indexOf('_') + 1, str.indexOf('.'));
        var curImg = parseInt(strCurrNo);
        var nextNo = imgCnt > curImg ? curImg + 1 : 0;

        $(this).fadeOut(400, function() {
            $(this).attr('src', str.replace("_" + strCurrNo, "_" + (nextNo)))
        }).fadeIn(400);


    });
});
```

A working [demo is added here](http://jsfiddle.net/gtB3t/1/)